# Submitting a job in Slurm using wrap

Tags: awk, bioinformatics, slurm, samtools

I am trying to create an automatic chain of commands for analyzing biological data. 
For this I am using Samtools in Slurm cluster. This line below is one of the commands I run for the analysis: 
`samtools view -h file.sam | awk '$6 ~ /N/ || $1 ~ /^@/' | samtools view -h > spliced.file.sam` 
Using this, I get my expected output (simple). 
However, when I want to insert the command into a job with `--wrap` I get a syntax error.

As presented:

```
sbatch --wrap "samtools view -h file.sam | awk '$6 ~ /N/ || $1 ~ /^@/' | samtools view -h > sp.file.sam"

    awk:  ~ /N/ ||  ~ /^@/
    awk:  ^ syntax error
```

Using `srun` at the start of the command and `&` at the end, are very helpful when submitting, but can I use it when I want to create a pipeline of commands? And can I add a dependency for this command? Is there a possible way to use the

 `--wrap` for this command?

I am aiming to create a automatic pipeline of commands, as the link below shows -
https://gencore.bio.nyu.edu/building-an-analysis-pipeline-for-hpc-using-python/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the `’` in the awk command with  ` \ ` ?

Comment: Use a workflow framework like nextflow, snakemake, or cromwell when handling jobs big enough to warrant using a cluster :) it will take some time to learn but save tons in the end.

Comment: I've never heard of `sbatch` so I might be way off but it sounds like something is interpreting `$6` and `$1` before awk gets to see them so try changing those to `\$6` and `\$1`.

Comment: that's because you used double quotes around and there is awk with `$6` and `$1` there and those `$` operators need to be escaped `\$6` and `\$1` to parent them expanding by the shell as special as mentioned by @EdMorton too

Comment: thank you Ed Morton and αғsнιη for your help, it worked!

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to do that would be to write the

```
samtools view -h file.sam | awk '$6 ~ /N/ || $1 ~ /^@/' | samtools view -h > spliced.file.sam
```

line to a shell script (e.g. `myscript.sh`)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file=${1?Usage: $0 <file.sam>}

samtools view -h "$file" | awk '$6 ~ /N/ || $1 ~ /^@/' | samtools view -h > spliced.file.sam
```

so that you can then issue

```
sbatch --wrap "./myscript.sh file.sam"
```

without the burden of managing shell escape with quotes. This would further allow you running commands like this

```
find . -name \*.sam -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} sbatch --wrap "./myscript.sh {}"
```

that will submit one job per `.sam` file found in the current directory, or use it in a Python script like the reference you mention.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the single quotation. You can do

> sbatch --wrap="samtools view | head| awk '{print}'"

and it'll work just fine.

When you don't want to save the command in a shell script, you need to escape the dollar sign inside the AWK command.

> sbatch --wrap "samtools view -h file.sam | awk '\$6 ~ /N/ || \$1 ~ /^@/' | samtools view -h > sp.file.sam"

The error is:

> awk:  ~ /N/ ||  ~ /^@/

Compare to the command you ran, neither field operator ($6 and $1) made it into sbatch submit, which means mostly likely the dollar sign was giving you trouble. I had a similar problem and escaping all $ worked for me.